Hair Particle System Crash
My project file crashes when trying to render a hair particle system. Sometimes it crashes before a frame renders, sometimes it crashes after multiple frames have rendered. The weird part is that the file is only using a fraction of my available VRAM (peaked around 4.9gb/24gb), which is what usually leads to these crashes. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Link to project file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UJgUbWitWy6qTb2cbVriG7LQ-ABtTCBZ/view?usp=sharing

If Blender crashes, you can file in a bug report. Go to Help > Report a Bug.

Are you sure it's the hair particles that crash Blender? The alembic(?) *.abc files are missing. So I've transfered the weights from the body and the pose renders fine. Peak VRAM was ~9.5 GB, came down to ~7.5GB, RAM is ~5GB. It's kinda heavy for just a single model in the scene. IDK why it takes so much memory. Next, I've removed the Subdivision Surface modifier from the jacket/shirt, and lowered the Max Samples to 32, no crash & -30% render time. If you do not take a complete close-up of the hair, you will not need a maximum of 500 samples for a simple toon shader style.

Hey there, thanks for the response! It ended up being an issue with my CPU. Running it on "Power Saver" mode seemed to stop the crashing.
